# How to generate PDF in Rails 5 Grape API endpoint and send in response?

Tags: pdf, ruby-on-rails-5, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf, grape-api

I am using `rails 5` and `grape gem` for building my application. Now I have a requirement of generating a PDF and send back to the response using `grape` endpoint. I am using `wicked_pdf` gem and `wkhtmltopdf-binary` for generate PDF. But I am facing the issue of `undefined method 'render_to_string'`.
I have tried various way to resolve it. but couldn't find any solution.

Below is my code snippet

API Endpoint:

```
module Endpoints
  class GeneratePdf < Grape::API
    get do
      users = User.all # I want this users list in my PDF
      pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(render_to_string('users/index.html.erb')) # placed in app/views/users/pdf.html.erb
      # some code here for send pdf back to response
    end
  end
end
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
```

Config > initializers > mime_types.rb

```
Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

`Grape::API`, don't have a `render_to_string` method that you can call on it, unlike a typical Rails controller. You should be able to replace that with something similar to this:

```
require 'erb'
binding_copy = binding
binding_copy.local_variable_set(users: User.all)
template = File.open(Rails.root.join('app/views/users/index.html.erb))
string = ERB.new(template).result(binding_copy)
pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(string)
```